# Visual Studio Code Intellisense Javascript import

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am testing if Visual Studio Code is the right code editor for me for js scripts.

Currently I cannot get intellisense to work on imported classes with es6.

I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly, but after following some documentation and other stackoverflow questions on exports I still can't get it to work. I also already put common js and allowSyntheticDefaultImports as true in the js.config file.

```
export class SimpleClass{
  constructor() {

  }

  getName(){
      console.log(name);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: commonJS uses requre(), not import. Try changing `module` in `jsconfig.json` to "es2015".

Comment: You may need to do `from './mainClass.js'`, it probably thinks what you're doing is an absolute import, and looking in node_modules

Comment: I changed to './mainClass.js', and nothing changes still intellisense doesn't activate. Also tried changing module to 'es2015' and again nothing changed.  Is the file structure correct? I'm not sure since this is the my first time using this editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to fixed it by changing my settings importing line looks like

```
    {
   "compilerOptions":{
      "target":"es6",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
   },
}
```

It seems my import line was incorrect and then I changed it to import{SimpleClass} from "./mainclass"